# Android: Show Facebook app with intent.creatChooser

Tags: android

I am trying to show the facebook app to share a line of text when a button is clicked. Now the chooser actually works and shows a bunch of apps but not facebook. Not sure if it's because of ACTION_SEND but here is what I have. Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
public void invite(View view){
  Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
  sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<p>I just      played Trivia Knowledge on Android. Think you can beat my Score?</p>"));
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Invite Friends To Play Trivia Knowledge"));
 }
```

Comment: Presumably Facebook does not support sharing HTML via `ACTION_SEND`.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not support the html type intent. Use text/plain instead. They do not support pre-filling the message as well according to the policy documentation.

[Android Intent Sharing Broken](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423)

Hope this helps.